# Lumen Dependency Injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection, lumen

As the last comment of [this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/register-middleware-via-service-provider/?page=2) it states the following:

> You can easily do it in any service provider (boot would be a nice place since we can use method based DI).

```
public function boot(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel $kernel) {
 $kernel->appendMiddleware('Sheepy85\L5Localization\Middleware\Localization'); // prependMiddleware works too.
}
```

This is Laravel Code for injecting a middleware from a Service Provider.

I am trying to achieve the same thing from *Lumen Framework*, here's the code:

```
<?php namespace Acme\Slz\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SlzServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     * @param Kernel $kernel
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Kernel $kernel)
    {
        // push the serializer middleware to the stack
        $kernel->pushMiddleware(Acme\Slz\Middleware\Serializer::class);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     * This service provider is a great spot to register your various container
     * bindings with the application. As you can see, we are registering our
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

But this raise the following error:

```
lumen.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Argument 1 passed to Acme\Slz\Providers\SlzServiceProvider::boot() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel, none given
```

Are there some more stuffs to do to enable the Dependency Container with Lumen ?

Comment: Probably, you can register your middleware in `bootstrap/app.php` http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/middleware#registering-middleware

Comment: I'd rather avoid, as I would like to write a module that registers a middleware, that's why I'm willing to do it in the service provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
<?php namespace Acme\Slz\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SlzServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // push the serializer middleware to the stack
        $this->app->middleware([
            'serializer' => 'Acme\Slz\Middleware\Serializer',
        ]);
    }
}
```